# Graceful shutdown of multithreaded java server using executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, shutdown

I refactored a single-threaded server to be capable of multithreading and accepting multiple clients at the same time. To do so, I spawn a new `ClientHandler` thread for each new client and submit it to an `ExecutorService`. I  want to initiate a server shutdown by entering a new line to `System.In`.

However, I am not able to shut down the server from within (using the shutdown method suggested in Oracle's ExecutorService doc)  - can somebody explain to me why?
My `Server` is a `Runnable` and I put it into the same `ThreadPool` as my individual client threads - could this be the problem?

*PS: This is a university project. I deliberately left out the names of the implemented interfaces and the request processing methods, as well as renamed the classes to prevent this from becoming the go-to solution for every lazy student in the future.*

**Server**

```java
public class Server extends Runnable {

  private final List<ClientHandler> activeHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
  private int port;
  private volatile boolean terminated = false;
  private ExecutorService service;


  @Override
  public void start(int port) throws ServerException {
      this.port = port;
      service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      service.submit(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void shutdown() throws ServerException {
      System.out.println("Shutdown initiated.");
      this.terminated = true;
      PoolUtil.safeShutdown(service);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
          while (!terminated) {
              try {
                  Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                  ClientHandler clientSocket = connect(client);
                  service.submit(clientSocket);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.err.println("ERROR: Connection to client failed.");
              }
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println("ERROR: Could not create a socket on port " + port);
      } finally {
          PoolUtil.safeShutdown(service);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public ClientHandler connect(Socket client) {
      ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(client, this);
      activeHandlers.add(clientHandler);
      System.out.println("Registered new ClientHandler for " + client.getInetAddress().toString());
      return clientHandler;
  }

  @Override
  public void disconnect(ClientHandler clientHandler) {
      activeHandlers.remove(clientHandler);
      System.out.println("Client successfully disconnected.");
  }
}
```

**ClientHandler**

```java
ublic class ClientHandler extends Runnable {
  private final Socket client;
  private final DirectoryServer server;
  private boolean terminated;
  private final Result result = new Result();

  public ClientHandler(Socket client, DirectoryServer server) {
      this.client = client;
      this.server = server;
      terminated = false;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      try (client;
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
           ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream())) {
          while (!terminated) {
              Object message = ois.readObject();
              if (message instanceof SomeRequest) {
                 // dostuff...
              } else if (message instanceof TerminateConnection) {
                  TerminateConnection termination = (TerminateConnection) message;
                  process(termination);
              } else {
                  System.err.println(
                          "ERROR: the received object of class "
                                  + message.getClass().toString()
                                  + "can not be processed."
                  );
              }
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // FIXME: Error handling
          System.err.println("ERROR concerning client " + client.getInetAddress() + " -> " + e.getMessage());
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          // FIXME: Error handling
          System.err.println("ERROR: the class of the received object unknown to server --> " + e.getMessage());
      }

  }


  @Override
  public void process(TerminateConnection terminateConnection) {
      this.terminated = true;
      server.disconnect(this);
  }
}
```

**ServerMain**

```java
public class ServerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServerException, IOException {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.start(1337);
        System.out.println("Server started. Press enter to terminate.");

        System.in.read();

        server.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Server is shut down...");
    }
}
```

**PoolUtil.shutdown( )**

```java
public static void safeShutdown(ExecutorService threadPool){
        threadPool.shutdown();
        try {
            // Waits a minute for all tasks to terminate
            if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                // Cancel all tasks that are still running after a minute
                threadPool.shutdownNow();
                // Waits another minute for all tasks to be cancelled
                if (!threadPool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                    System.err.println("Service did not terminate!");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have an `awaitTermination()` after `shutdownNow()`? I've seen examples where there was no `awaitTermination()` after `shutdownNow()` but after`shutdown()` alone.

Comment: @AliasCartellano It's just the way [Oracle proposes to shutdown ExecutorServices](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). I guess the additional `awaitTermination()` is kind of an extra layer of thread-safety - although I too do not understand its necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDoc for the [ExecutorService.shutdown()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) method states that it means "previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted". Termination, however, will not happen until all tasks have completed.  The Runnables for your tasks perform a blocking operation,
`serverSocket.accept()` so you should not expect the awaitTermination method to return after a shutdown until enough requests come in after the shutdown to use up all of the tasks that are blocking.  You could try using shutdownNow() instead of shutdown() so that it attempts to immediately cancel/interrupt all of the running tasks, which should hopefully unblock them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed the class to have the serverSocket as instance variable, so that I can call its `close()` method from within `shutdown()`. This triggers an `IOException` from the accepting socket, which I catch by terminating the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@njr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5780020/njr) I realized that `serverSocket.accept()` was the source of my problems.

The method is blocking and waits for incoming connections. To be able to terminate it, I made `serverSocket` an instance variable that I can close by calling `serverSocket.close()` from within my `shutdown()` method.

This will cause `serverSocket.accept()` to throw an `IOException` - so I catch it and call `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to shutdown the running thread.

Below is the relevant code:

```java
public class Server extends Runnable {

    private final List<ClientHandler> activeHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
    private ServerSocket newConnections;
    private volatile boolean terminated = false;
    private ExecutorService service;


    @Override
    public void start(int port) throws ServerException {
        try {
            this.newConnections = new ServerSocket(port);
            service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            service.submit(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServerException("Server can not be created at port " + port);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() throws ServerException {
        try {
            this.terminated = true;
            newConnections.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServerException("Shut down failed - server socket can not be closed");
        } finally {
            PoolUtil.safeShutdown(service);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (!terminated) {
                try {
                    Socket client = newConnections.accept();
                    ClientHandler clientSocket = connect(client);
                    service.submit(clientSocket);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("ServerSocket terminated");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            PoolUtil.safeShutdown(service);
        }
    }

    // left out irrelevant methods

}
```